# Creating a target system

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making a target in Unity that looks like a dartboard with three different levels of scoring depending on where you shoot. The issue is that the Score Text wont change when I shoot on the target. I'm a novice and I "translated" below code from  Javascript and wondering if you experts could see 
if there is any issues with the code?

GlobalScore (attached this to an empty gameObject. I draged the text 'ScoreNumber' to ScoreText slot in Unity)

```
 using System.Collections;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using UnityEngine;
 using UnityEngine.UI;


 public class GlobalScore : MonoBehaviour {

 public static int CurrentScore;
 public int InternalScore;

 public GameObject ScoreText;

 void Update () {
    InternalScore = CurrentScore;
    ScoreText.GetComponent<Text>().text = "" + InternalScore;

  }

}
```

ZScore25 (created 3 scripts (ZScore25, ZScore50, ZScore100) which I attached to the three cylinder gameObject I created)

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ZScore25 : MonoBehaviour
{

void DeductPoints(int DamageAmount)
 {
    GlobalScore.CurrentScore += 25;
 }
}
```

---

HandgunDamage Script

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class HandGunDamage : MonoBehaviour {

public int DamageAmount = 5;
public float TargetDistance;
public float AllowedRange = 15.0f;



void Update () {
    if (GlobalAmmo.LoadedAmmo >= 1) { 
    if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1"))
    {
        RaycastHit Shot;
  if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position,  transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward), out Shot))
            {
                TargetDistance = Shot.distance;
                if (TargetDistance < AllowedRange)
                {
                    Shot.transform.SendMessage("DeductPoints", DamageAmount, SendMessageOptions.DontRequireReceiver);
                }

            }
        }
    }

}
```

}

Comment: How are you triggering `void DeductPoints(int DamageAmount)`?

Comment: Hi, I have attached a mesh collider to the object and it should be triggered by my shots.

Comment: I've added HandgunDamage script above

Comment: Right, cause in my experience with Unity I normally would take the approach to using either a Box (or relative shape) collider or a mesh collider.  Then I use the methods exposed by Unity API `void OnTriggerEnter(Collider collider)` and `void OnTriggerExit(Collider collider)` (see here: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnTriggerEnter.html).  Then I would place your logic of point deduction within the body of the `OnTriggerEnter(...)` based on whether the collider triggered was that of the mentioned target (check by name or tag).

Answer (score 0):

Debug.Log (or breakpoints) help you to see where the problem lies. I tested your case with minor changes and the score text value was changing.

I replaced ZScore25,50,100 scripts with a single ZScore script that has score as public field which you can set in the editor.

```
public class ZScore : MonoBehaviour {

    public int Score;

    public void DeductPoints() {
        Debug.Log("CurrentScore += " + Score);
        GlobalScore.CurrentScore += Score;
    }
}
```

..and then I used raycast (the example script below was attached to camera):

```
void Update () {

    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) {
        var lookAtPos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint (new Vector3 (Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, Camera.main.nearClipPlane));
        transform.LookAt (lookAtPos);
        RaycastHit Shot;
        if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, transform.forward, out Shot))
        {
            Debug.Log ("Raycast hit");
            var score = Shot.transform.GetComponent<ZScore> ();
            if (score != null) {
                Debug.Log ("Hit ZScore component");
                score.DeductPoints ();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for helping, feel like hitting my head against a wall at this point. Could you please let me know where I should put above camera script? Should I add it to an existing script  (making an FPS and have a First person Controller script and a Player Casting script where I think it could be added) Or should create an empty game object, add script and attach to the camera component? thank you!

Comment: If you want to test the Update method above, add a new script to the camera and then copy-paste the update method to the new script. The script just makes camera to instantly face mouse click position. Thus, it may interfere with your other scripts. Also, changing camera orientation instantly is not visually pleasant. The code snippet was added just as an example.

Comment: My steps: 1. Created new UI-Text  -- > added  "ScoreLabel" witch child "ScoreNumber"2. Created empty GameObject "ScoreKeeper". Added "Global Script" above and dragged "ScoreNumber" into "Score Text" 3. Created three 3D Cylinder GameObjects. Re-shaped so the looked like a dartboard. Deleted Box Collider, added Mesh Collider 4. Created "ZSCore" script and dragged these to the different Cylinder GameObjects. I do have an enemy script attached to other game objects which works fine/gets destroyed by bullets. Should I add that code to my main post? Thank you so, so much again for your help!

Comment: Have you added Debug.Log prints to see what part of your code is being executed when you shoot at the dartboard?

Comment: I added example Debug.Log to the code in the answer. You could instrument your code in similar fashion. Then you could check which logs appear in the console output.

Comment: Raycast hit
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
HandGunDamage:Update() (at Assets/Scripts/HandGunDamage.cs:23)

Comment: Hit ZScore component
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
HandGunDamage:Update() (at Assets/Scripts/HandGunDamage.cs:29)

Comment: I received these messages, do you know what they mean? thank you /C

Comment: the "meaning" of the messages depends on where the Debug.Log prints are located in the code. I would guess that raycast part of your code works fine, but there is something wrong in showing text on UI.